# Migration version development and deployment using Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restx

i have a published API service on cloud using flask-restx and flask-sqlalchemy. on my local i have so many migration version the structure will look like this:

- migrations

  - versions

    - update_1.py
    - update_2.py
    - update_3.py
    - update_4.py

but on my production the structure will look like this:

- migrations

  - versions

    - update_1.py

and i deploy my service to prod, and run `python3 manage.py db migrate` the output look like this:

`INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl. INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.`

what can i do to make my production environment same as my local?